# Qt QSqlQueryModel::setQuery control what display in in the column

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Im using :

```
QString query = "SELECT foo,n1,n2 FROM play_list";
QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(query, queryDB);
```

in QSqlQueryModel subclass , but i dont want to display all the results that i getting from the select , i want to use the data and display only foo in the display and others results 
in others things . 
how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `QSqlQueryModel` what you should do is provide your own custom implementation of `QAbstractItemModel`, which you would set as a model for something like `QTableView` and you will run the query to get the data separately and populate your custom model which will display anything you choose.

Comment: Any more information about how to populate a `QAbstractItemModel` with the result of a query?

Answer (score 0):

For a QTableView, you can use `void QTableView::setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide)` to hide specific columns from your model.